# What is the original name of this game "Marble Wow"?

Tags: identify-this-game

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/norGQ.png]

Anyone know another (hopefully original) name for this game explained in this youtube video?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrjvrB6V_EY

The description says it is ancient and of Asian origin but thats it.

- Board: 4x4 grid.
- Players: 2
- Pieces: 4 pieces per player.
- Setup: All 8 pieces on board forming an X.
- Movement: 1 piece per turn, moves in single direction until stopped by wall or other piece.
- Win: players pieces in one of these patterns:2x2 square, or 4 corners, or straight orthagonal line.
- Rules: If player blocks one of opponents pieces from moving, opponent wins.

I'm sure it wasn't played with marbles, but probably wood tokens or if indeed Asian, then Go pieces perhaps.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That game was published under the name **Dao** in 1999. No mention on the [BGG entry for Dao](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/948/dao) of a prior version of that game, so I assume that's the original incarnation.

Comment: Almost exactly a year this question has been bugging me and I am THRILLED to finally have the answer! Thank you. Wow, 1999, so "ancient"!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a varient of Neutreeko, which can be played on [Board game arena](https://en.boardgamearena.com/#!gamepanel?game=neutreeko).
The variant on BGA is slightly different:

- Board: 5x5 grid.
- Pieces: 3 pieces per player
- Movement: same
- Win: players pieces in one of these patterns: straight orthagonal line or diagonal line.
- Setup:

[image]

for farther reading see > http://www.neutreeko.net/neutreeko.htm